# Outlook 2010 Instant Search not available (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, search

Suddendly my Instant Search Bar disappeared and was replaced by the old not-working Search Bar. I really do not have any idea how this happened.

I tried most of the solutions I found on the Internet:

- Check that local Exchange cache is still enabled
- Repair PST files with SCANPST.EXE
- Rebuild Windows Search Index
- Turn off then on Windows Search
- Remove and add Outlook folders in Windows Search locations
- Start with a fresh OST file rebuilt from scratch
- Repair Office 2010 installation
- Reboot my PC numerous times

I am out of possible solutions but still stuck with my old not-working search bar :-(

Any new idea?

Comment: For an unknown reason, the Instant Search Bar reappeared!

I was looking into solutions to backup/restore my Outlook settings so as to uninstall and re-install Office. Launched Outlook to check my mails. The old bar appeared and one second later was replaced by the full featured Instant Search Bar...

Happy but confused!

Comment: Should this question be closed or removed?

Comment: Probably closed but how can I do that?

Comment: You can delete it I think